# Enter password only once for three "git clone"s in a script

Tags: git, bash

I want to create a bash script in Linux with clone repositories from git.
I want to write the script in the way that I want need to type the username and password.

My script looks:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone http://xxx
git clone http://yyy
git clone http://zzz
```

When I'm running this script, I need manually to insert the username and the password 3 times (for 3 repository: xxx, yyy, zzz).

Is it possible to  update the script so the username and password will be inserted automatically ?

Comment: HTTP is **really** the wrong protocol to use for authenticated git access. Even if you store the password the "supported" way, it's still in plaintext somewhere any other process can read it -- and even if you don't store it at all (and enter it via Expect -- or just have the user type it three times), any process sniffing packets can read it out of memory or off the network (meaning anyone with access to a router between you and the website can intercept your password). Just say no.

Comment: Also, this is a very git-specific question, not a generic linux/shell question. I've updated title and tagging appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You should create ssh key pair, deploy ssh-public key to these three repositories and clone them using **ssh url** instead of **http**.

In this way you won't be prompted for username or password.

Command to create ssh key pair:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`

Keys will be created at `~/.ssh` by default. Public key will be saved as `id_rsa.pub`

Find more details about creating and adding ssh keys to github repo [here.](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

Comment: Well, yes, that is the correct way to do it, but creating the key-pair doesn't quite finish the process as it relates to github. It would be helpful to the questioner if you provided the links to the github help page for creating and transferring the public key to your github account.

Comment: Added link to github documentation.

Comment: There you go, much more helpful for the original poster, and all those with a similar question that end up here. Good job.